# Are $\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cardinals

Are $\mathbb{N}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

There are any difference between isomorphism and cardinal equality? If $X$ and $Y$ are two sets and $\text{Cardinal}(X)=\text{Cardinal}(Y)$, is $X$ isomorpic to $ Y$?

Comment: Isomorphic as what? In the category of sets, isomorphisms are precisely the same as bijective maps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking at $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ purely as sets then the answer is 'yes'. In that case bijections are isomorphisms. If structure is added (e.g. order or composition) then more is needed. The bijections that preserve and reflect the structure are isomorphisms.

Comment: In first case, we can looking a set, such as an $(0)-type$ structure? (Ring is $(2,2,0)$ types, group is $(2,0)$, Boolean algebra is $(2,2,1,0,0)$)

Comment: Actually we are looking at categories.